# How to show email or mobile in secure way via php?

Tags: php

Suppose :-
I fetch the data from database of user there I fetch email or mobile number.

```
$mob = mobile;
$email = email;
```

I want it look like this :

```
Email = ab*******@g***.Com
Mobile = 12****8***
```

I I make this?

Comment: Please add additional specification to the problem you are facing. Do you want the email and mobile number to be shown like that on the front end, do you want them to be shown like that on the back end or do you want to store them like that in the database ?

Comment: Only front end I want show like secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple functions

```
function obfuscate_email($email, $secure_param) {
    list($name, $domain) = explode("@", $email);
    $name = substr($name, 0, $secure_param) . str_repeat("*", strlen($name) - $secure_param);
    $domain = explode(".", $domain);
    $domain[0] = substr($domain[0], 0, $secure_param) . str_repeat("*", strlen($domain[0]) - $secure_param);
    $domain = implode(".", $domain);
    return implode("@", [$name, $domain]);
}

function obfuscate_phone_number($phone_number, $secure_param) {
    return substr($phone_number, 0, $secure_param) . str_repeat("*", strlen($phone_number) - $secure_param);
}

$email = "example@domain.com";
$phone_number = "500600700";

echo obfuscate_email($email, 3) . PHP_EOL;
echo obfuscate_phone_number($phone_number, 5) . PHP_EOL;
```

Result

```
exa****@dom***.com
50060****
```

Comment: In mobile what we do when we need like this : 12****6***. `obfuscate_phone_number($phone_number, 2) . obfuscate_phone_number($phone_number, 1) .PHP_EOL;` is this correct?

Comment: Pls reply, say something

Comment: @Albert divide `$phone_number` into two strings (using `substr`) and use function like you say: `obfuscate_phone_number($phone_number_first, 2) . obfuscate_phone_number($phone_number_last, 1)`

Comment: I want direct fetch data from database and then show this secure formate. How we do that?